# M-x command completions to all occurrences of a substring

Tags: completion, commands, m-x

If I do `M-x insert TAB`  Emacs shows a list of possible completions like below

```
Possible completions are:
insert-abbrevs              insert-anniversary-diary-entry
insert-block-diary-entry    insert-buffer
insert-char                 insert-cyclic-diary-entry
insert-diary-entry          insert-file
insert-file-literally       insert-kbd-macro
insert-monthly-diary-entry  insert-pair
insert-parentheses          insert-register
insert-weekly-diary-entry   insert-yearly-diary-entry
```

What if one likes to have a list of all completions in which the string `insert` exists, for example `auto-insert` which is not given in the above list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*insert` <kbd>TAB</kbd> will work for `execute-extended-command`,
but [smex](https://github.com/nonsequitur/smex) is just much better.

Answer (score 3):

Others have mentioned `smex` and `icicles` which give such completions. I'll add [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm). Install from MELPA with `M-x package-install helm`.  `(helm-mode t)` will turn it on globally.  It doesn't steal your `M-x` key for itself, so also add `(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x)` to give it the key.

Answer (score 1):

In [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) you get such completion using **`S-TAB`** (by default - you can change the key, of course).

By default:

- **`TAB`** gives you prefix completion. (Or vanilla Emacs completion - e.g., `*insert TAB` will do as @abo-abo indicated.)
- **`S-TAB`** gives you "*apropos*"-style (i.e., regexp) completion, which of course includes substring completion.

Just use a different completion key, `TAB` or `S-TAB`, to get a different kind of completion. And for each of these keys you can use different completion *methods*, including various fuzzy completion methods. You can cycle among the methods using **`C-(`** (for `TAB`) and **`M-(`** (for `S-TAB`).

All of this is true not only for `M-x` but for *everything* - any minibuffer input completion.

---

And BTW, Icicles does *not* "steal" your `M-x` key. Whether you keep `M-x` bound to standard command `execute-extended-command` or you bind it to Icicles multi-command `icicle-execute-extended-command` is up to you. And in either case you can take advantage of Icicles completion when `icicle-mode` is turned on. (If you turn off `icicle-mode` then you are back to vanilla Emacs behavior, for `M-x` and for everything else.)

By default, you do get special [multi-command behavior for `M-x`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi_M-x), but it is trivial to customize option [**`icicle-top-level-key-bindings`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Bindings#IcicleModeBindings) to choose which keys you want to have take advantage of any special Icicles commands.